# some python exercises and need some input

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the exercise.

> Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers
>   until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the
>   largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other
>   than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an
>   appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter the numbers from the
>   book for problem 5.1 and Match the desired output as shown.

The result should be:

```
Invalid input  
Maximum is 7  
Minimum is 4
```

My code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")        
    if num == "done" : break
    if len(num) < 1 : break        
    try :
        num = int(num)
    except :    
        print "Invalid input"
        continue        
print "Maximum", largest
print "Minimum", smallest
```

Why is the program not printing out the largest and smallest?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because they're both still `None`, you never reassign them. Explain your code to a rubber duck, you'll soon see the problem.

Comment: You don't store the numbers, and you never change the `largest` and `smallest` variables from `None`.

Comment: Curious - if you are just now learning Python, why aren't you learning on the most recent version (3.5)?

Comment: @Nicarus well the course is being taught in this version, and the python code interpreter the teacher uses is also in an older version.

Comment: Use infinity for max and min to force always true for first number and allow to run in both python 2 and 3. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never entered a value for largest and smallest.

```
largest = float('-inf') # Always smaller than any number
smallest = float('inf') # Always larger than any number
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")        
    if num == "done" : break
    if len(num) < 1 : break        
    try :
        num = int(num)
    except :    
        print "Invalid input"
        continue
    # set largest and smallest
    # initial inf forces first entry to reset the value
    largest = max(largest, num)
    smallest = min(smallest, num)
    # Because None is always smaller than any integer

print "Maximum", largest
print "Minimum", smallest
```

Comment: Some nasty if/then blocks - why not just use `max()` and `min()`?

Comment: @Nicarus Fixed to use = - infinity as initial value to avoid if

Comment: @Nicarus i'm just starting, i only know a couple of functions, but thanks for the input i read about them and i used them just like in the code above.

Comment: @sabbahillel thanks a lot i went to read about max, min and inf and not only fixed the problem but i also learned a few more built in functions.

Comment: @RicardoFernandes If you like the answer, check the accept button or upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: @sabbahillel i did upvote, i got some msg saying that votes cast by ppl with less than 15 reputation are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score. :(